# Meaning of the Jews’ response in John 8:41?

Tags: john, jesus, cultural-analysis

John 8:41 (NASB)

> …They said to Him, “We were not born of fornication; we have one Father: God.”

What was the intent/meaning behind these words? Did the Jews really view God as their Father, or was this some sort of retort to Jesus? Did Jewish people of the time not consider their physical parents legitimate and primarily thought of themselves as born of God?

Answer (score 4):

In this passage, Jesus is demonstrating how wisdom can silence reasoning. And whenever that happens, the result is anger - every time, even ‘today’. These Jews were finally beginning to recognize through Jesus’ statements that there was more to being a Jew than being a physical descendant of Abraham, and they became very offended.

Via wisdom, Jesus had them take a stand or position that they accused him of taking. In their effort to qualify spiritually as Jews, they did exactly what they had sought to kill Jesus for. They said that God was their Father! Earlier in John we see ..

**JOHN 5:18** *This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God.*

And now, it was they *themselves* claiming God as their father!

**JOHN 8:41** *You are doing the works your father did.” They said to him, “We were not born of sexual immorality. We have one Father—even God.”*

Jesus had twisted their accusations against themselves! And it was this that provoked the reaction.

Jesus, in His wisdom, “made foolish the wisdom of this world” (1 Corinthians 1:20).

One further clarification. It was the Pharisees who were disputing here, not the Jews ‘in general’. The issue was with the religious leaders, not the people.

Comment: Wow, I never thought about the fact that the people make the same claim as Jesus, but Jesus was getting persecuted for it. This is really helpful, thank you! The reason I wrote “Jews” instead of Pharisees was because earlier in the chapter it doesn’t specifically say Jesus was speaking to Pharisees, only “Jews who believed in Him” in verse 31.

Comment: @Gremosa  Yes, I probably shouldn’t have emphasised the distinction’ between the Jews [people] and the Leaders [Pharisees]. The people always looked to their leaders for interpretation. When we say ‘the Jews’ rejected their Messiah, it was *only* because the people always let their leaders make the decision(s) for them. They [the people] didn’t actually reject him. Nevertheless,  throughout the OT, God always let the leader speak for the people, and acted on whatever the leader said/did.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the context of John 8 gives you the answer to your question about the meaning of John 8:41, “…They said to Him, We were not born of fornication; we have one Father: God.”

Even though the idea of God as Father was not prevalent in Jewish culture before the time of Christ, the Old Testament does talk about God as Father.  The Pharisees would have been very familiar with the scripture references. Here are some examples: Isaiah 63:16, Deuteronomy 32:6, Jeremiah 3:19 and:

> Isa 64:8  But now, O LORD, thou art our father; we are the clay, and thou our potter; and we all are the work of thy hand.

To the Pharisees, lineage was very important as they traced their inheritance as the seed of Abraham physically through their family lines. Your lineage proved you were a true child of Israel. To the religious Jews, just the fact that you were part of the direct line of Abraham was good enough to claim your inheritance as part of Israel and linked you to God as Father.

So both Jesus and the Pharisees identified with God as Father.

However, in Matthew 8:19, Jesus brings the relationship with the Father to a more intimate level to where Jesus by His statement, is claiming equality with God.

> 19 Then said they unto him, Where is thy Father? Jesus answered, Ye neither know me, nor my Father: if ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also.

Here, Jesus increases the claim to not just having God as His father but saying that if you know Jesus you know the Father. In the mind of a Pharisee, this is blasphemy.

So then, in John 8:41, the Pharisees are taking a deliberate shot at Jesus’ family lineage by their words, “We were not born of fornication”. By this time in Christ’s ministry, the Pharisees had heard the story of Jesus’ birth. So their crude response is a purposeful insult; in calling Him a bastard, they are casting aspersions on His lineage and His claim to be part of the family of God.

Answer (score 2):

The word *father* appears 21 times in John 8. It was a point of contention between Jesus and the people.

They had trouble understanding what Jesus meant by the word.

> 19 Then they asked him, “Where is your **father**?”
>
> “You do not know me or my **Father**,” Jesus replied. “If you knew me, you would know my Father also.”

> 27 They did **not understand** that he was telling them about his **Father**.

> 41 You are doing the works of your own **father**.”
>
> “We are not illegitimate children,” they protested. “The only **Father** we have is God himself.”

The word *father* was somewhat meaningless to them in this dispute. They were just being argumentative and contentious no matter what Jesus said.

> 42Jesus said to them, “If God were your **Father**, you would love me, for I have come here from God. I have not come on my own; God sent me. 43Why is my language **not clear** to you? Because you are unable to hear what I say.

That was their mindset. They were not reasoning logically.

> 44 You belong to your **father**, the **devil**, and you want to carry out your father’s desires.

Their minds were messed up by the lies of the devil.

Did the Jews really view God as their Father, or was this some sort of retort to Jesus?

They retort with whatever was in their heads. They were not thinking clearly.

Did Jewish people of the time not consider their physical parents legitimate and primarily thought of themselves as born of God?

Clear thinking Jews did think of the LORD as their Father as in
Isaiah 63:16

> Yet You are our **Father**, though **Abraham does not know us** and Israel does not acknowledge us. You, O LORD, are our **Father**; our Redeemer from Everlasting is Your name.

Answer (score 2):

Yeshua ben Panthera - Yeshua (Jesus) son of Panthera, Panthera is a Roman soldier, this is how Jesus is named in the Talmud. The Pharisees do not believe in a virgin conception of Jesus but call Mariam a whore among the Roman soldiers.

I believe that it is him they refer to as being **born of fornication** when the father to them was not know nor no proper registration of birth and father certificate which they the Pharisees would hold in the temple.

Commentaries hold the believe that they refer to the surrounding nations and their idoltery as to mean being born under fornication.

> **We be not born of fornication**.—The meaning of this is to be found in the fact that the word became in the Old Testament prophets a
> frequent symbol for idolatry. Comp. Isaiah 1:21; Jeremiah 2:20;
> Jeremiah 3:8-9; Ezekiel 16; Hosea 1:2 (especially), 4:12, and 5:7.)
> They, as distinguished from the nations among whom they dwelt, had
> maintained a pure monotheism, and had never been idolaters, or
> children born of spiritual fornication. Ellicott's Commentray

This is what the Pharisees penned down about Jesus;

> Sanhedrin 106a, **Jesus' mother was a whore**: "She who was the
> descendant of princes and governors played the harlot with
> carpenters."

> Shabbat 104b it is stated that in the "uncensored" text of the Talmud
> it is written that Jesus mother, "Miriam the hairdresser," had sex
> with many men. "**Jesus was a bastard born of adultery**."

> (Yebamoth 49b, p.324). "**Mary was a whore**: Jesus (Balaam) was an
> evil man." (Sanhedrin 106a &b, p.725). "Jesus was a magician and a
> fool. Mary was an adulteress". (Shabbath 104b, p.504).

I hold the believe that John 8.41, "**We be not born of fornication**", was in fact a slanted suggestion that the legitimacy of His birth was in question.

Answer (score 1):

Scripture indicates that Jews considered God their Father.

Isaiah (eighth century B.C.) laments the falling away of Israel from God their father, despite the promises and the blessings and the redemptions that happened up to his day:

> **Isaiah 63:16** For **thou art our father,** and Abraham hath not known us, and Israel hath been ignorant of us: **thou, O Lord, art our father,** our redeemer, from everlasting is thy name.

Tha author of *Wisdom* (first century B.C.) characterizes pagans and the unjust as persecuting "the righteous one" (probably standing for the good Jewish person observing the Law), and portrays them as mocking the fact that he calls himself the son of God and that he has God for his Father:

> **Wisdom 2:12-20** Let us therefore lie in wait for the just one, because he is not for our turn, and he is contrary to our doings, and upbraideth us with transgressions of the law, and divulgeth against us the sins of our way of life. 13 He boasteth that he hath the knowledge of God, and **calleth himself the son of God.** 14 He is become a censurer of our thoughts. 15 He is grievous unto us, even to behold: for his life is not like other men's, and his ways are very different. 16 We are esteemed by him as triflers, and he abstaineth from our ways as from filthiness, and he preferreth the latter end of the just, and **glorieth that he hath God for his father.** 17 Let us see then if his words be true, and let us prove what shall happen to him, and we shall know what his end shall be. 18 For if he be the true son of God, he will defend him, and will deliver him from the hands of his enemies. 19 Let us examine him by outrages and tortures, that we may know his meekness and try his patience. 20 Let us condemn him to a most shameful death: for there shall be respect had unto him by his words.

This shows that before Christ, God was certainly considered a Father to Israel.

In the New Testament period, we know that people were given theopatronymic names (yes, I made a new word).

> **Matthew 27:13** And he had then a notorious prisoner, that was called **Barabba.**

Inasmuch as the name *Barabba* means "Son of the Father" ('son of Abba'), this shows that Jewish parents were wont to consider God their Father so much that they called their children, 'Son of Abba.' (Contrary to popular belief, *Abba* is not a diminuitive or childlike way of saying Daddy, it is Aramaic for THE Father, or in the vocative, "[O] Father").

(The final *s* of Barabba*s* in the Greek New Testament is a product of Greek grammar only, and doesn't represent a variation on Barabba.)

Moreover, when Jesus told people how to pray, it's not evident He was teaching them something radically new (i.e. in how to specifically address God). So that when He says, "Our Father, who art in heaven" (*abouna d'bishmaya*), it would not have been seen as a new way of concieving of God, but rather serves as a template to how to properly pray to the God they alread knew (i.e. as a Father figure).

The greatest testimony is from an enemy. As such, the fact that Jews, who from the crucifixion of Christ to present constitute the greatest opponents of Christianity (as to informed and opposite rejection, rather than indifference to beliefs but hatred of pratice etc.) retain the address "Father" (usually as 'your Father' or 'my Father' 'in heaven') in some of their prayers and in the Talmud. It's unthinkable that peopel who so viscerally opposed the idea that God had a son should otherwise commonly employ the appelation Father for God themselves, especially in prayer, and especially using the phrase "Father in heaven," as Jesus uses it.